# Is xsymbols used in Isabelle/JEdit?

Tags: isabelle, jedit, xemacs

In the section 4.1.2 of the [Isabelle/HOL tutorial](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle/doc/tutorial.pdf) we find

> By convention, the mode of "xsymbols" is enabled whenever Proof General's X-Symbol mode or LaTeX output is active.

Now, with the fading of Proof General, is there any relevance of xsymbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsymbols` mode is still the default in Isabelle/jEdit.

While Isabelle/jEdit renders symbols in the editor as unicode, behind the scenes the internal representation is still using the `xsymbol` encoding. This can be seen by opening saved theory files up in another editor. For example, the text:

```
lemma "a ∧ b ⟹ b ∧ a"
  by simp
```

is saved to a file as its `xsymbols` encoding:

```
lemma "a \<and> b \<Longrightarrow> b \<and> a"
  by simp
```

The Isabelle plugin to jEdit performs the translation to and from unicode as it communicates with the main Isabelle process. (The translation tables can be seen in `Isabelle/etc/symbols`, if you are curious.)

The practical consequence of this is if your are defining notation, `xsymbols` refers to all of LaTeX, ProofGeneral and Isabelle/jEdit.

Perhaps in the future there will be a `unicode` mode, replacing the internal `xsymbols` representation, but we are not there yet.

Comment: Concerning speculations about "unicode mode": This was already dismissed in 1998 and replaced by "Isabelle symbols", which are documented in the various reference manuals.